# calling alert from code behind not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am showing an alert via

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", 
             "alert('" + ex.Message.Replace("'", "") + "');", true);
```

in the catch block of server side button click. But I am calling another script manager in the first line of button click as

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", 
              "$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_rwsender').show();
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_rfvsender'), true);", true);
```

In this case, it doesn't show alert message, but first line script is working.

If I remove first line script code, alert is working. Whats relation between two different script manager and why does a script effect another script? 
How can I achieve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Second Will not work , because you send Js instruction directly to Script Manager , ( note that alert is window native function , that's why it works )

Just declare in your client  side (aspx) a function :

```
function ShowElement(){
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_rwsender').show();
    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_rfvsender'), true);
}
```

Then call this last in the backend :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "show",'ShowElement()', true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert","alert('" + ex.Message.Replace("'", "") + "');", true);
```

Note the the key must be unique for each registred script , 
here the first is registred as "show" and alert "alert"

Just form Information prevent using sush a generated cleint ID in your js code :

just use `document.getElementById("<%=NameOfYourControl.ClientID %>"), true);`
instead of hardcoded value : `ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_rwsender` .

Comment: @onur If this helped you , please up and mark the answer as resolved ✓ (left the answer ) ( like in this image => [image resolve] post(http://i.stack.imgur.com/T8umg.png) ) thank you

Comment: I am calling 'alert' as second actually. First, I call function which shows or hides a div. I tried your solution but sadly it didnt solve. I am calling function like ShowElement() several for different divs. and after that, I m calling alert. Show element is working, alert is not working.

Comment: @onur I forget to mention that if you want to register two script just specify different key for each one of them , Please see my updated answer !

Comment: @onur , Hi , if that solve your issue , could you please mark the answer as resolved thank you :) +1

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP*).

The problem was key parameter of RegisterStartupScript. Both are alert. I changed them to Guid, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

can you try this? 
`Response.Write("<script>alert('Alert!');</script>");`

you can add your js code inside script tag

```
Response.Write("<script>$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_rwsender').show();</script>");
```